# Dynamic Configuration of Spring Security form-login attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Using form-login for authentication. I need to be able to configure the failure-url and success-url from a database table we have for configuring other aspects of the application.

My application which this authenticates users for is linked to from a different application which may be on this server or another server and I need to fail back there or go there when the user logs out.

```
 <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                    always-use-default-target="true"
                    authentication-failure-url="**/failureurl.aspx**"
                    default-target-url="/home/configuration"/>
<logout logout-success-url="**/successurl.aspx**" invalidate-session="true"/>
```

How would I change these attributes on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have logic processing that determines where the user actually lands. If I were you, I'd wire your attributes to be intercepted by another controller that processes the request based on your rules and the redirect from there.

```
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                authentication-failure-url="/redirect/failure"
                default-target-url="/home/configuration"/>
```

And then:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/redirect/failure")
public class Redirector
{
    public String doFailureRedirection(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
    {
          //check where user is supposed to go and return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can configure them dynamically - you are better pointing to controller methods that read the database properties, and then redirect to the appropriate page.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"", "/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirectToHomepage(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // If not logged in, then go to the landing page.
    if (request.getUserPrincipal() == null) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin");
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/dashboard");
}
```